# What is the difference between Input Method (IM) and Input Method Editor (IME)?

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard, input-languages

What I have derived from my research is that there are three tasks that are required for me to write in Japanese using my English keyboard.

1. User Interface
2. Conversion of my input from English to Japanese
3. Communication of my input to the conversion program and from there to the user interface

Below are my three thought paths and the resources that have led me to those thought paths. I cannot reach a conclusion as to which one is the right one.

1. **Input Method** and **Input Method Editor** are terms that are used interchangeably. (I reached this conclusion just while surfing through the many pages of information)
2. **Input Method** is the methodology, while the **Input Method Editor** is the actual implementation. [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method)
3. **Input Method** is the component that handles the conversation, while the **Input Method Editor** handles the user interface. [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Input_method_editor)

#### References

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Input_method_editor

[3] https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Input_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there ever was a distinction between the two terms, I think that
it was lost a long time ago.

Almost all sources, including the ones you included, don't differentiate
between the two. I have searched some more, and almost all the sources
that I found say "input method (or input method editor)".

This uniformity of terminology might arise from the fact
that it's used this way in Wikipedia, so is cited in this same way.

In my opinion, any attempt to define differently these two terms is not
supported by any source and would be a fruitless philosophical effort.